# Changing value in rectangular two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am creating a very rudimentary battle ship program for fun and I 
have come across a problem with changing values in my rectangular two dimensional array. Essentially, there are five "ships" placed in this two dimensional array. A user then inputs an integer to see if they hit or miss. I wanted the output to display the array with the guessed number represented with an `X` for a miss and a `0` for a hit. I am having trouble with changing the value at `area[i][j]` when it equals the value of `t` to the `0` or `X`. I am new to java so I am trying to learn. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
public class battleship {

    //Rudimentary Battleship game
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Hello and welcome to a basic version of Battleship.");
        System.out.println(" The objective of this game is to sink all five ships located on the grid listed below.");
        System.out.println(" Follow the prompt located underneath the grid ");
        final int ROWS = 10;
        final int COLS = 10;
        int sum = 0;
        int [][] area = { {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
                  {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20},
                  {21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30},
                  {31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40},
                  {41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50},
                  {51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60},
                  {61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70},
                  {71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80},
                  {81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90},
                  {91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100} };

        for(int i=0; i < area.length; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < area[i].length; j++) {


              if(area[i][j] < 10) 
                System.out.print("   "+(area[i][j])+" ");  
              else if(area[i][j] < 100) 
                System.out.print("  "+(area[i][j])+" ");
              else 
                System.out.print(" "+(area[i][j])+" ");
            }
          System.out.println("");
        }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);{
    System.out.println("Enter attack integer:");
    int t;
    while(true){
    t = input.nextInt();

    if ((t == 41) || (t == 42) || (t == 43)){
    System.out.println("Hit - Destroyer");}

    if ((t == 80) || (t == 90) || (t == 100)){
        System.out.println("Hit - Submarine");}


    if((t == 52) || (t == 62) || (t== 72) || (t == 82) || (t == 92)){
        System.out.println ("Hit - Aircraft Carrier");}

    if((t == 15) || (t == 16) || (t == 17) || (t == 18)){
        System.out.println ("Hit - Battleship");}

    if((t == 1) || (t == 2)){
        System.out.println ("Hit - PT Boat");}
    else{
        System.out.println ("Miss");
    }
    System.out.println("You have fired at:" + t);
    int w = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < area.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < area[i].length; j++) {

            if (area[i][j] == t)

          if(area[i][j] < 10) 
            System.out.print("   "+(area[i][j])+" ");  
          else if(area[i][j] < 100) 
            System.out.print("  "+(area[i][j])+" ");
          else 
            System.out.print(" "+(area[i][j])+" ");
        }
      System.out.println("");
    }

        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To change the value at [i, j] simply do `area[i][j] = "whatever";`

Comment: Not really your question but you can initialize your 2D array 'area' a lot better with two for loops instead of typing it all manually in.

Comment: 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
  11   12   13   14 ... 100 this is the out put currently. lets say the user guesses "1" i need the position at "1" to change to a 0 for a hit and an X for a miss. While printing out the rest of the above output. Such as:  X    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20 
  21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30 
  31   32   33   34   ... 100

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I rewrote it using booleans. Much easier and what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, modifying your code:

```
if ((t == 41) || (t == 42) || (t == 43)){
    System.out.println("Hit - Destroyer");
    area[i][j] = "X";
}
if ((t == 80) || (t == 90) || (t == 100)){
    System.out.println("Hit - Submarine");
    area[i][j] = "X";
}
if((t == 52) || (t == 62) || (t== 72) || (t == 82) || (t == 92)){
    System.out.println ("Hit - Aircraft Carrier");
    area[i][j] = "X";
}

if((t == 15) || (t == 16) || (t == 17) || (t == 18)){
    System.out.println ("Hit - Battleship");
    area[i][j] = "X";
}
if((t == 1) || (t == 2)){
    System.out.println ("Hit - PT Boat");
    area[i][j] = "X";
}
else{
    System.out.println ("Miss");
    area[i][j] = "O";
}
```

A note: be careful, arrays are 0 indexed, so your ship positions don't exactly correspond to the way you set up the grid. i.e. area[4][1] is not "41". You seemed to do this correctly (in the case of the destroyer) for the columns but not the rows. The if statements should check for 31, 32, 33 if the ship is at area[4][0], area[4][1], area [4][2]. In fact, you might be better off labeling the positions from 00, 01, 02, ... , 97, 98, 99 so that the indices correspond to the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You would be much better off using object orientation. Here's a skeleton to get you started:

```
public class Cell {
  private boolean ship = false;
  private boolean hit = false;

  public boolean getHit() {
    return hit;
  }
  public void setHit(boolean hit) {
    this.hit = hit;
  }
}
```

Then

```
public class Board() {
  public static final int SIZE = 10;
  private Cell[][] board;

  public Board() {
    board  = new Cell[SIZE][SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        board[i][j] = new Cell();

  public boolean getHit(int x, int y) {
    if(x < 0 || x >= SIZE || y < 0 || y >= SIZE) throw new BattleshipException("You queried a cell that doesn't exist!");
    return board[x][y].getHit();
  }
  // etc etc.
}
```

Flesh out all the methods you need, add fields when you need them, this will work much better!